# Is $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{8k+2}}$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I used the Leibniz theorem to prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{8k+2}}$ convergences. However, it does not say anything about absolute convergence. Is there a way to find out whether or not the series is absolutely convergent?

Comment: Note that without the alternating sign it’s a lot like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{1/2}}$.

Comment: You can use the following inequality $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{8k+2}} \ge \frac{1}{8k+2} \ge \frac{1}{8k+8}$.

Comment: Use the limit comparison test for your series with $$\sum\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is absolutely convergent if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converges. Applying this here just removes the alternating $(-1)^k$ and the sum becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{8k+1}}$$

This sum diverges by the comparison test and therefore the series is not absolutely convergent.